# How to make a object moving - How to make game with VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

How to make a object moving on the screen- How to make game with VB.NET
- In 2d game, ex i see a mario charator, which is object ( Label, image v.v.v)
- Is there a  physical engine for vb.net
Sorry, bad english

Comment: You should probably add xna and game-development tags to this question, it might attract some more relevant answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into [XNA](https://web.archive.org/web/20100904170002/http://creators.xna.com:80/en-GB/), although most examples are done in C#.

Start off by looking at a few [tutorials](https://web.archive.org/web/20100610061933/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/coding4fun/archive/2007/02/20/1727608.aspx) and then try making a simple game for yourself (do not start off with Mario etc as this is too complex for beginners. Think more along the lines of Pong).

Get yourself a good book, for example [http://www.amazon.com/Learning-XNA-3-0-Game-Development/dp/0596521952](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596521952)

Also check out [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/), an open source alternative for building DirectX apps in .Net.
DirectX is a set of Microsft APIs for dealing with Game Development

Comment: I think if you're going to start XNA then you might want look into learning the c# language, as pretty much all samples will be done through it. It will not take too long to pick it up if you're already familiar with vb.net

Answer (score 3):

look at XNA for .NET game developing

[XNA Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791.aspx)

If you don't want to use this or other framework, you've to write a lot of code, need mathematic background etc.

Answer (score 1):

The basic premise is that you have a timer running and on each tick of the timer, you determine how much your objects should move then refresh the screen.  This is going to be a relatively fast timer (faster than .5 seconds, anyway) and will determine how smooth your animations are.

There are probably engines in VB.Net somewhere, but you really don't need to worry about what they're written in.  They're likely to be distributed as a library and you can mix and match the languages as much as you want, as long as the projects are separate.

As others have mentioned, though, you should look at Microsoft's XNA framework.  Most of the examples are written in C#, but [this guy](http://www.alanphipps.com/VisualBasicdotNET-XNA-XNAEngine.html) has tutorials about how to do VB.Net with XNA.  His site is currently over its bandwidth limit, so [here's](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tBnZ-L95544J:www.alanphipps.com/VisualBasicdotNET-XNA.html+vb.net+game+framework&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) a google cache version (hit ctrl+a to see the text as his font is a light blue and the cache is making the background white)

Comment: On what, exactly?  VB.Net and XNA?  Game programming in general?  XNA tutorials?